# How to write a conditional in template code evaluating the result of a Low Variable containing a conditional?

Tags: low-variables, low

I have the following line in my template code

```
    <li class="{if node_has_children}has-dropdown{/if}{if node_id == {lv-seg1-taxonomy-node-id}} is-lvl1-active{/if}">
```

The conditional that contains the Low Variable
**{if node_id == {lv-seg1-taxonomy-node-id}} is-lvl1-active{/if}** always returns true despite {node_id} != {lv-seg1-taxonomy-node-id} when output into the template, and I always get the is-lvl1-active class.

The contents of the LV is:

```
{if segment_1 == 'youth'}41{if:elseif segment_1 == 'open'}42{if:elseif segment_1 == 'competition'}43{if:elseif segment_1 == 'theme'}44{if:elseif segment_1 == 'films'}45{if:elseif segment_1 == 'news'}46{if:else}{/if}
```

The Low Variable is set to early parse. How do I compare its output to a tag in the main template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the content of the `lv-seg1-taxonomy-node-id` variable is that big `if`-statement. Then you're using the LV as part of another conditional: the one in your first example.

This will not work because of [Parse Order](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html#rendering-stages).

Your variable is set to parse early, which means the template will change this:

```
{if node_id == {lv-seg1-taxonomy-node-id}}
```

to this:

```
{if node_id == {if segment_1 == 'youth'}41{if:elseif segment_1 == 'open'}42{if:elseif segment_1 == 'competition'}43{if:elseif segment_1 == 'theme'}44{if:elseif segment_1 == 'films'}45{if:elseif segment_1 == 'news'}46{if:else}{/if}}
```

Which is an invalid conditional.

Early parsed vars, like Snippets, **will not evaluate before hitting the template**. Instead, the variable name is replaced by its contents.

You will have to find a different way to set the class name.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - looks like it's JavaScript time.